# Approach for changing edittext to dropdowns at runtime?

Tags: android, view, runtime

what would be a good approach for the following?

EditText
EditText
EditText

the above three edit texts are how I have my xml layout. Depending on the users settings up on the server.. these edittexts need to be changed to a dropdown.

so for dropdowns if field1 is false field2 is true and field3 is false it would look like

EditText
DropDown
EditText

Should I

1. do it all programatically at runtime,
   removing existing views from xml and putting an empty ViewGroup in its place
2. have both options for each field in xml, and only show valid one (seems inefficient)
3. some other approach I havent thought of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use [ViewStubs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html). The view isn't inflated until you do it. You would have 6 ViewStubs but only 3 would get inflated at RunTime.

Answer (score 2):

you can put both edittext and dropdown on a FrameLayout, with edit text being in front.
then, on edit activation or any other logic - you can switch them... same thing can be done with ViewFlipper, etc.

Comment: I have used this approach before, it works well but I am going to explore Robby Pond's solution this time. thank you though.